# Pygame how to change size of a surface?

Tags: pygame, geometry-surface

How do you change the size of a surface in pygame that has an image (not scaling). When I load an image in pygame the surface becomes the size of the image. I need to change the size of the surface to be the size of a frame (sprite sheet).

Here is code I used to solve issue (thanks to Chris Dennett):

```
self.surface = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
self.surface.blit(pygame.image.load(imageName).convert_alpha(), (0,0), (0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight))
```

Comment: Not really, I'll answer.

Comment: The [surface docs](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) mention a constructor that takes both a size, and another surface: `pygame.Surface((width, height), flags=0, Surface): return Surface`.  But it is not clear on whether it copies that surface, or just copies the _attributes_ of that surface.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that. I'm not sure it'd work in this case. I think it just copies the surface attributes, so might be useful in maintaining the same colour depth / pixel format and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new surface, passing in the desired width and height as arguments (i.e., how big the sprite is). Then use `newsurf.blit(spritesheet, (0, 0), (posX, posY, newsurf.getWidth(), newsurf.getHeight()))`. Should work. Then you can use newsurf as your sprite. `posX` and `posY` should be the x and y you want to blit from in your sprite sheet respectively.

Comment: problem solved. Thanks a bunch: self.surface.blit(pygame.image.load(imageName).convert_alpha(), (0,0), (0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight))

Comment: Oh, you want to avoid loading the sprite sheet over and over. It's really inefficient :)

Answer (score 5):

For sprite sheets, you have 2 good options.

#### 1) Load spritesheet as one Surface.

When blitting, use the source rect argument. This will blit just one frame, from the sheet.

#### 2) Use subsurfaces.

Load spritesheet as one Surface.
Load a subsurface, of each frame you want : http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.subsurface

As far as you are concerned, the subsurface is a 'new' surface, with the width and height of the cell. But, it's not duplicate memory. It's linked.

From the docs:

> Returns a new Surface that shares its pixels with its new parent. The
> new Surface is considered a child of the original. Modifications to
> either Surface pixels will effect each other. Surface information like
> clipping area and color keys are unique to each Surface.